# Custom domain(Hostiner) in heroku not working without www

Tags: heroku, dns, subdomain, hosting, web-hosting

Recently i have purchase domain from hostinger and using heroku hosting but some how my domain working only with www. when i try to access url like example.com it shows me hostinger page.
i have tried follwoing name as domain name in heroku custom domain setting.

```
www.example.com
example.com
*.example.com
```

and tried using dns target of above url in my hostinger domain setting in CANME but its still not working.
what should i put in hosts part of hostinger and where its should be exactly pointed to.

Please help me to solve the error...

Comment: please provide me your domain name. So, i can check it @proBot

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se]. In the future, please ask similar questions there.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add the domains on Heroku.

Project > Settings > Add Domain

[image]

On popup, enter the first domain. "example.com".

Copy the DNS Target Value

[image]

On hostinger, you need to add CNAME @ {link that you have copied previoulsy}

---

Second, repeat for www. domain

Copy the DNS Target Value

Add CNAME www {link that you have copied previously}

---

To enable SSL:

On Heroku, go to Project > Settings > Configure SSL

Select the option that you want:

[image]

And now, you have WWW and non WWW domains configured.